# Append text to a file after a regular expression in linux

Tags: regex, linux, nginx, awk, sed

I would like to add additional lines of text to the configuration of the nginx file. I wrote a regular expression [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/XTGGJb/1), although it does not work with sed. What should the script look like that will add text after the found text?

I'm trying use this command, but without success:

```
sed '/location \/ {(\n|.)*?[a-zA-Z0-9 \n;#._\/=$,]*}/r nginxphp.txt' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Most important in this question is **How should look regex in sed syntax?**

or just another way to inject some lines to file in debian (in my example)
I would like to make change in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules;
    }
HERE SOME TEXT
```

Comment: Is the content of `nginxphp.txt` a single line or multi-line? If multi-line then show an example of it's contents in your question so we can see if it also contains lines that match your regexp or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using this `gnu awk`:

```
awk -i inplace -v RS='\n[[:blank:]]*location / {[^}]*}' '1
RT {
   print RT 
   if ((getline < "nginxphp.txt") > 0)
      print
}' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

- `RS='\n[[:blank:]]*location / {[^}]*}'` matches complete `location` block and makes it a record separator.
- `print RT` prints this matched text
- `getline` function reads `nginxphp.txt` in memory, that gets printed using `print` statement afterwards.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! It is worth adding that to save the performed operation, add the `-i inplace` parameter

Comment: If that getline fails your script will quietly and cryptically re-print the whole of your "default" file preceding that "location" line. It will also add an extra blank line after the "location" line and at the end of the output and after the contents of "nginxphp.txt" and if THAT file contained a line matching the "location" regexp then you'd just get the part before that. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when and how to use getline.

Comment: Fair points Ed and thanks for the useful link on `getline`. I have edited it now.

Answer (score 2):

With sed :

```
sed '/location \/ {/!b;:A;N;/}/!bA;r nginxphp.txt' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Comment: This also look nice, but in default config file i've got multiple location key (second is commented) so i think this script should add this file once

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want, using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { new=$0; next }
{ print $0 (RT ? RT new : "") }
' \
ORS="" \
RS='^$' nginxphp.txt \
RS='(^|\n)[[:blank:]]*location */ *{[^}]*} *\n' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```